# How to get CMS (PKCS#7) from PKCS#1 Zeal id integration

Tags: java, itext, digital-signature, itext7, pkcs#7

I am integrating CSC2QR zeal id integration. where i am sending the Base64 URL encoded SHA256 hash (OGRlY2M4NTcxOTQ2ZDRjZDcwYTAyNDk0OWUwMzNhMmEyYTU0Mzc3ZmU5ZjFjMWI5NDRjMjBmOWVlMTFhOWU1MQ==) for signature and in response I am getting PKCS#1 raw signature .  I am stuck on how I can use this information to digitally sign the document. I am using itext7 .

```json
"signatures": [
    "uXPiaQOEToyju50OIMrNe5gTstUQhnufmlcxmI9mG5tPCCMDYdfEV4Y+gKkixdzD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\r\nFoQ+J1teMOok/`sbO2X90SNqg5jvsyFTCBrGSgGWSob1TFghgWgRNiDBienXWWY09`\r\noaii058RhlJDm5l1KhMurBUZsyAre9rs74qj5tntMyQ="
  ]
```

I am also getting signer certificate as a response
Response -:

```json
{
  "authMode": "oauth2code",
  "cert": {},
  "key": {
    "algo": [
      "1.2.840.113549.1.1.11"
    ],
    "len": 4096,
    "status": "enabled"
  },
  "lang": "en-US",
  "multisign": 1
}
```

Comment: As an aside, comparing the [ZealiD API reference](https://developer.zealid.com/reference/getting-started-with-csc-2qr-api-1) with your Credentials Info response, it looks like you are using the CSC API, not the CSC 2QR API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I don't know the CSC 2QR API, let alone have finished code for addressing it. Thus, in this answer I'll show up a frame to integrate an arbitrary remote signing API.*

The easiest way to integrate remote signing services with the iText 7 signing API is to implement the `IExternalSignature` accordingly. That may look like this (code specific to the CSC 2QR API represented by pseudo code):

```java
public class CSC2QRSignature implements IExternalSignature {

    Certificate[] chain;
    String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
    String encryptionAlgorithm = "RSA";

    public CSC2QRSignature([... parameters you need for CSC 2QR communication ...]) {
        [... request your CSC 2QR Credentials Info and initialize      ...]
        [... chain, hashAlgorithm, and encryptionAlgorithm accordingly ...]
    }

    @Override
    public String getEncryptionAlgorithm() {
        return encryptionAlgorithm;
    }

    @Override
    public String getHashAlgorithm() {
        return hashAlgorithm;
    }

    public Certificate[] getChain() {
        return chain;
    }

    @Override
    public byte[] sign(byte[] message) throws GeneralSecurityException {
        byte[] digest = MessageDigest.getInstance(hashAlgorithm).digest(message);
        [... call CSC 2QR Sign Hash for the base64 encoded digest ...]
        [... and return the base64 decoded signature from the response ...]
    }
}
```

Using that class you can sign a PDF like this:

```java
PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(SOURCE_PDF);
OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(RESULT_PDF);

CSC2QRSignature signature = new CSC2QRSignature(...);
IExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();

PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, os, new StampingProperties());
signer.signDetached(digest, signature, signature.getChain() , null, null, null, 0, CryptoStandard.CMS);
```

Comment: Hi @mkl, I am facing one issue here , i need to pass same hash value in second authorize api before calling the signHash api ... if i am calling inside sign method the value of hash will be change.

Comment: Simply do *all* calls from within the `sign` method.

Comment: Thanks, for the help ! .... actually here second authorize call is from browser only ....but np  i found the solution for that ...really appreciate your help

Comment: Hi @mkl , pdf have successfully signed but while validating from https://ec.europa.eu/digital-building-blocks/DSS/webapp-demo/validation . I am getting Signature format:
PDF-NOT-ETSI

Comment: *"I am getting Signature format: PDF-NOT-ETSI"* - Indeed. You have not mentioned that you have require a PAdES style signature. As a first step you should use `CryptoStandard.CADES` instead of `CryptoStandard.CMS` in the `signer.signDetached` line. This should allow for PAdES BASELINE-B.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for your reply... Actually I am using signdefered instead of signdetached because I need hash before calling for remote signature ... Is there any way I can get the same hash which I am getting in sign method

Comment: In the case of above approach

Comment: If you are using deferred signing, you have a first signExternalContainer pass. The dummy external container you use there needs to use `ETSI_CAdES_DETACHED` instead of `Adbe_pkcs7_detached`. Furthermore, the CMS signature container you inject must be built for PAdES. In particular it needs an ESS cert id v2 attribute and it must not have a signingTime attribute.

Answer (score 1):

*In comments it became clear that you do not consider doing all the signing service related stuff in the `sign` method of an `IExternalSignature` implementation (as I proposed in my other answer) an option. Instead you prefer to go for deferred signing.*

*In your attempt at deferred signing you created the CMS signature container to embed in the PDF in the most simple form. As you want to create PAdES signatures, though, this simple format is not valid, a more complex CMS container profile is required. For details see ETSI EN 319 142-1.*

*This answer, therefore, focuses on creating a PAdES BASELINE compatible CMS signature container for the hash of the byte ranges determined in the first step of a deferred signing use case. In the second step this signature container can then be embedded into the prepared PDF.*

*There are two principal options, one can try and extract the code iText uses for this, or one can use a CMS builder code of some security library, e.g. BouncyCastle, directly. We're using the first approach here.*

Thus, let's dissect `signer.signDetached` and find out how it creates a CMS signature container for the hash of the signed byte ranges of the prepared PDF in the other answer.

The relevant code in that method is

```java
PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7((PrivateKey) null, chain, hashAlgorithm, null, externalDigest, false);
if (signaturePolicy != null) {
    sgn.setSignaturePolicy(signaturePolicy);
}
InputStream data = getRangeStream();
byte[] hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, SignUtils.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm, externalDigest));
List<byte[]> ocspList = new ArrayList<>();
if (chain.length > 1 && ocspClient != null) {
    for (int j = 0; j < chain.length - 1; ++j) {
        byte[] ocsp = ocspClient.getEncoded((X509Certificate) chain[j], (X509Certificate) chain[j + 1], null);
        if (ocsp != null) {
            ocspList.add(ocsp);
        }
    }
}
byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, sigtype, ocspList, crlBytes);
byte[] extSignature = externalSignature.sign(sh);
sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, externalSignature.getEncryptionAlgorithm());

byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, sigtype, tsaClient, ocspList, crlBytes);
```

For a PAdES BASELINE signature CRLs and OCSP responses are not added to the signature container. And for BASELINE-B we don't even need a TSA client

Thus, in your case you can proceed like this:

```java
try (
    InputStream resource = ...;
    ByteArrayOutputStream preparedArrayStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream()
) {
    IExternalDigest externalDigest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    String digestAlgorithm = "SHA256";

    // deferred signing, step one
    String base64DocumentHash = prepareSignature(resource, preparedArrayStream);
    // prepare PdfPKCS7 with document hash
    byte[] hash = Base64.decodeBase64(base64DocumentHash);
    PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7((PrivateKey) null, chain, digestAlgorithm, null, externalDigest, false);
    byte[] sh = sgn.getAuthenticatedAttributeBytes(hash, CryptoStandard.CADES, null, null);
    // retrieve signature bytes:
    // * calculate hash of sh, 
    // * prepare ZealId signature request for hash of sh (QR code etc)
    // * request signature value for hash of sh
    byte[] extSignature = ... signature value for hash of sh ...;
    // finalize PdfPKCS7 with signature bytes
    sgn.setExternalDigest(extSignature, null, "RSA");
    byte[] encodedSig = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7(hash, CryptoStandard.CADES, null, null, null);
    // deferred signing, step two
    try (ByteArrayInputStream preparedInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(preparedArrayStream.toByteArray())) {
        createSignature(preparedInputStream , Base64.encodeBase64String(encodedSig));
    }
}
```

Of course you must delete the `PdfPKCS7` code from your `ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer`, so it burns down to

```java
class ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer extends ExternalBlankSignatureContainer
{
    byte[] cmsSignatureContents;

    public ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer(byte[] cmsSignatureContents) {
        super(new PdfDictionary());
        this.cmsSignatureContents = cmsSignatureContents;
    }

    @Override
    public  byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws CertificateException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
        return cmsSignatureContents;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you so much @mkl....let me try above approach

Answer (score 0):

Here is my code after getting signature from zeal . The signature are valid but still showing PDF-NOT-ETSI.

```
public static  String  prepareSignature(InputStream in, ByteArrayOutputStream preparedArrayStream ) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException,GeneralSecurityException {
            PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(in);
             Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(36, 648, 200, 100);
            PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, preparedArrayStream,  new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
                
PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = signer.getSignatureAppearance();
                appearance.setPageRect(rect)
                .setPageNumber(1)
                .setLocation("EU")
                .setReason("Test");
               signer.setFieldName("testing");
                
                PreSignatureContainer external = new PreSignatureContainer(PdfName.Adobe_PPKLite,
                        PdfName.ETSI_CAdES_DETACHED);
                
                signer.signExternalContainer(external, 8192);
                String hash = Base64.encodeBase64String(external.getHash());
                return hash;
               // byte[] preSignedBytes = os.toByteArray();
              //  outputStream.close();
                
            
            //return outputStream;
        }
        static class PreSignatureContainer  implements IExternalSignatureContainer 
        {
            private PdfDictionary sigDic;
            private byte hash[];
    
            public PreSignatureContainer(PdfName filter, PdfName subFilter) {
                sigDic = new PdfDictionary();
                sigDic.put(PdfName.Filter, filter);
                sigDic.put(PdfName.SubFilter, subFilter);
            }
    
            @Override
            public byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws GeneralSecurityException {
                String hashAlgorithm = "SHA256";
                BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
    
                try {
                    this.hash = DigestAlgorithms.digest(data, digest.getMessageDigest(hashAlgorithm));
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new GeneralSecurityException("PreSignatureContainer signing exception", e);
                }
    
                return new byte[0];
            }
    
            @Override
            public void modifySigningDictionary(PdfDictionary signDic) {
                signDic.putAll(sigDic);
            }
    
            public byte[] getHash() {
                return hash;
            }
        }
    
    public static void createSignature(InputStream in, String signatures) throws Exception {
             byte[] decodeSignature = Base64.decodeBase64(signatures);
             PdfReader reader =  null;
                reader = new PdfReader(in);
                FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File("D:\\zealid\\test\\newZeal.pdf"));
                 PdfSigner signer = new PdfSigner(reader, outputStream,  new StampingProperties().useAppendMode());
                 signer.signDeferred(signer.getDocument(), "testing", outputStream, new ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer(decodeSignature));
                
                
                    outputStream.close();
        }
    
    class ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer extends ExternalBlankSignatureContainer
        {
            byte[] cmsSignatureContents;
            public ExternalPrecalculatedSignatureContainer(byte[] cmsSignatureContents) 
            {
                super(new PdfDictionary());
                this.cmsSignatureContents = cmsSignatureContents;
            }
            
            
            @Override
            public  byte[] sign(InputStream data) throws CertificateException, InvalidKeyException, NoSuchProviderException, NoSuchAlgorithmException
            {
              BouncyCastleDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
             PdfPKCS7 sgn = new PdfPKCS7(null, chain, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, null, digest, false);
             sgn.setExternalDigest(cmsSignatureContents, null,"RSA");
             cmsSignatureContents = sgn.getEncodedPKCS7();
             
                return cmsSignatureContents;
            }
    
          
    
        
        }
```

Comment: The way you use the `PdfPKCS7` class you generate the most primitive type of CMS signature, without signed attributes, merely a simple wrapper around the signature value. The requirements for the signature container in a PAdES signature, though, enforce the use of signed attributes, in particular the ESS cert id v2 attribute.

Comment: if possible ..... can you please provide some example or reference ? That will be great help.... thanks again

Comment: Well, if you implemented signing as written in my answer, you wouldn't have to cope with these details. You said the trouble with doing so was that you *need hash before calling for remote signature.* In that case simply store the `CSC2QRSignature` constructor arguments (the *parameters you need for CSC 2QR communication*) in some member variables and start the communication after having calculated the `byte[] digest` in the `sign` method. All you need to switch to PAdES then would be to use `CryptoStandard.CADES` instead of `CryptoStandard.CMS` in the `signer.signDetached` call.

Comment: Thanks mkl , Actually i need hash before calling signDetached method .  Flow is i am generating url for QR code where i need to pass hash https://{url}?hash={HASH}. After scanning the QR code i am getting call in callback url . Then i need to request for sign hash where i need to pass same hash value which i am passing while genetrating QR code.

Comment: But why can you not simply do all of that in the `sign` method of `CSC2QRSignature` right after you calculated the hash?

Comment: Because we need to prepare QR code url https://{url}?hash={HASH} and open in browser then user will scan that QR code . If that hash is not required while creating QR code url then this will be a simple task we can perform all action inside sign method . But the issue is we need that hash before applying signature or before calling signDetached method .....  That is why i adopt signDefered because from PreSignatureContainer i am getting hash and allocating space for signature ..... Here is the flow https://developer.zealid.com/reference/sign-hash-1

Comment: Ah, ok, and you don't want to prepare that URL and have it opened in a browser from within the `sign` method, I assume. Or the overall architecture of your application does not allow that.